# Using ReactJS without a server

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm developing a site that will be ran inside Kiosk Pro and as such, it will need to be ran without a server.

I've added `homepage` to my `package.json` file and started using `HashRouter`, but after running the build and accessing the index.html file, I get this error in the browser: `react-dom.production.min.js:4636 TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`

Is there something else I need to add to my configuration?

Comment: Don't you have any errors on dev environment?
And can you include some of your relevant code?

Comment: No, it’s only when I’ve ran the build I’m getting the issues. I can add some code shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

I was getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined` due to one of the navigation components relying on `stateOpts`, which don't work with `HashRouter`, and not setting the `pathname` of the `NavLink`. I moved this logic into the component itself (which makes more sense anyway) and it worked!